# RC PWM video switch

Tags: wireless, switches, video, camera, ntsc

I'm currently working on a quadcopter that I'm equipping with several video cameras of various sizes/quality (i.e. one high quality, forward facing camera, then three or four cheap micro cameras arrayed all over the quad). My problem is this - switching between the 4 cameras. I'm looking to build a system similar to [THIS](http://www.rangevideo.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=7_55&products_id=175), however with 4 channels and (hopefully) for far less than they're charging ($35 + shipping). Instead of controlling it with an on/off switch channel on my transmitter, I'm using a spare knob (0 thru 25% = camera 1, 26% thru 50% = camera 2, and so on).

Will 4 reed or solid state relays attached to an 8-pin PIC / PICAXE be sufficient, or does switching video require more sophistication? Obviously this is all on board a small quadcopter, so I don't think there's a need for any amplification or noise filtering. I mainly ask this because all the R/C video switches I've seen look to be relatively complex devices, leading me to believe there's something more going on other than connecting a certain pin to an output pin.

Lastly, if it matters, all the cameras are the same resolution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done something similar with a PIC12F675 to switch (using a spare radio channel) 4 composite video signals to send to a wireless video transmitter (it was a car, not a quadcopter, but this makes no difference). 
But I've not used relays (altough they should work too) but a Maxim 4xSPST high bandwidth switch IC. It was the [IH5352](http://www.maxim-ic.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/1361) if I recall correctly.